# union of complexTypes in XMLSchema

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm writing a schema and found myself unable to specify an XML schema that allows both

```
<root>
  <content>icecream</content>
</root>
```

and

```
<root>
  <content><list>icecream</list></content>
</root>
```

and does not allow (mixed content)

```
<root>
  <content>blabla<list>icecream</list>hehe</content>
</root>
```

I first thought I could achieve this with a choice between elements with same name and a different type, but that failed. I also tried union, but since this is only defined for simple types it makes me wonder:  Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSD 1.1 you can have a complex type that allows the mixed content, and then restrict it with an assertion, for example:

```
<xs:assert test="exists(list) != exists(text())"
```

Answer (score 2):

(1) and (2) are possible with mixed-content, which is not compatible with (3). Therefore it is not possible.

Comment: Interestingly, it is possible to satisfy any two of the constraints together, but not all three.